# How to convert edmx (database first) to code first

Tags: entity-framework-5

I'm having a lot of trouble with a DB first approach to an oracle database. Most of the time when I try to update the model my update-wizard crashes. I'm pretty sure this has to do with ODP.net .

the DBA just added a column to the database and a few hours ago I was able to update my model from the database, but i had a few minor issues (one column was renamed etc..) So I decided to undo pending changes on my entire Solution and start over.
I've been trying a whole lot of stuff the last few hours to just update the model again but It has come to a point that my update-wizard constantly crashes when I perform a refresh of my tables.

I can't work like this anymore. Is there a way to convert my edmx file to a code first approach so that I don't need to perform this refresh anymore?

Much appreciated if anyone can guide me in the right direction here...

Comment: Apparently Update Wizard is not crashing it's just going so slow because Oracle decided to change execution plans for the queries of Entity Framework.. Resulting in queries lasting about 8 minutes whenver I press update model from database (while this morning the execution plan was different and the query only was 8 seconds).. this made me think that the update wizard was crashing

Comment: possible duplicate of [Tool to convert Entity Framework EDMX to Code First](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7333834/tool-to-convert-entity-framework-edmx-to-code-first)